# Reference book on large deviations for mean field theory

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, large-deviation-theory

I am looking for reference material, notes or published books, which study applications of large deviations on mean field theory / interacting particle systems etc.. I am especially interested in equilibrium large deviations if possible. 
Could you suggest me anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry i cannot put a comment since my reputation is low. The book by Firas Rassoul-Agha and Timo Seppalainen, A course on large deviations with an introdution to Gibbs Measures, might be helpful.